# How to create div to fill all space between header and footer div

Tags: css, html-table

I'm working on moving from using tables for layout purposes to using divs (yes, yes the great debate).  I've got 3 divs, a header, content and footer.  The header and footer are 50px each.  How do I get the footer div to stay at the bottom of the page, and the content div to fill the space in between?  I don't want to hard code the content divs height because the screen resolution can change.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

## Flexbox solution

Using flex layout we can achieve this while allowing for natural height header and footer. Both the header and footer will stick to the top and bottom of the viewport respectively (much like a native mobile app) and the main content area will fill the remaining space, while any vertical overflow will be scrollable within that area.

[See JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/osvx1zoo/3/)

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <header>
    ...
  </header>
  <main>
    ...
  </main>
  <footer>
    ...
  </footer>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header,
footer {
  flex: none;
}

main {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  flex: auto;
}
```

Comment: I have change the answer.  Yes, the original answer is outdated.

Comment: For Angular (tested in version 7) apps, use `html, body, app-root, <component selector>` and `body, app-root, <component selector>` instead of the first two style. It works for me.

Answer (score 35):

To summarize (and this came from the [CSS Sticky Footer](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/) link provided by Traingamer), this is what I used:

```
html, body 
{ 
    height: 100%; 
} 

#divHeader
{
    height: 100px;
}

#divContent
{
    min-height: 100%; 
    height: auto !important; /*Cause footer to stick to bottom in IE 6*/
    height: 100%; 
    margin: 0 auto -100px; /*Allow for footer height*/
    vertical-align:bottom;
}

#divFooter, #divPush
{
    height: 100px; /*Push must be same height as Footer */
}

<div id="divContent">
    <div id="divHeader">
        Header
    </div>

    Content Text

    <div id="divPush"></div>
</div>
<div id="divFooter">
    Footer
</div>
```

Comment: This is better than the famous http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm because the `<body>` color doesn't show through.

Comment: great answer. please explain why you have used "vertical-align:bottom;" in divContent ? is it required ?

Comment: @RezaSh - It was a long time ago that I came up with this pattern, so I do not recall why the need for "vertical-align:bottom" in divContent.  I tested it by removing that style using jsfiddle and everything still seemed to work, so perhaps that was a needless style.

Comment: This answer seems to outdated. Please check the fiddle posted in first comment!

Comment: Work fine, simple and clean +1, i suggest "0px to -100px

Answer (score 8):

To expand on Mitchel Sellers answer, give your content div height: 100% and give it a auto margin.

For a full explanation and example, see Ryan Fait's [CSS Sticky Footer](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/).

Since you know the size (height) of your header, put it inside the content div (or use margins).

Position absolute will give you problems if your content is larger (taller) than the window.

Answer (score 4):

A way to do this using CSS Grid:

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <header>Header</header>
      <section>Content</section>
      <footer>Footer</footer>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

**main.css**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
main {
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 100px auto 100px;
}
section {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS grid instead it is supported by nearly all the browser

```css
html{
    height: 100%;
}
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.main-body{
    display: grid;
    /* let content auto to occupy remaining height and pass value in fit-content with min-height for header and footer */
    grid-template-rows: fit-content(8rem) auto fit-content(8rem);
    grid-template-areas: "header" "main" "footer";
}

.main-header{
    background-color: yellow;
    grid-area: header;
}

.main-content{
    grid-area: main;
}

.main-footer{
    background-color: green;
    grid-area: footer;
}
```

```html
<body class="main-body">
    <header class="main-header">
        HEADER
    </header>
    <main class="main-content">
        this is content
    </main>
    <footer class="main-footer">
        this is footer
    </footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<body>
  <header>
  </header>
  <main>
    ...
  </main>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</body>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

header {
    height: 10px;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
}

footer {
    height: 10px;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
}
```

This css to body will make sure that header and footer are always on top and bottom respectively.

Put all the content in main.
going further you can make header or footer sticky as per your requirement.

Check the working example here
https://codepen.io/vishal657/pen/MWBOErq?editors=1100

Answer (score -4):

if you are trying to maximize the height of your content div, in the CSS add

height: 100%;

Comment: I found that if you have 3 divs, for example:

<div id="header">...</div>
<div id="content">...</div>
<div id="footer">...</div>

and you make the content div 100% height, it will size the the height of the page, but waht I want is for it to size to the height of the page minus the other divs

Answer (score -9):

```
#footer {
 clear: both;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't even begin to answer the question. The footer doesn't need to float anyway.