# How can I center content between a header and footer div?

Tags: css, html

In a previous question, I learned how to keep a footer div at the bottom of the page. ([see other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206652/how-to-create-div-to-fill-all-space-between-header-and-footer-div))

Now I'm trying to vertically center content between the header and footer divs.

so what I've got is:

```
#divHeader
{
    height: 50px;
}

#divContent
{
    position:absolute;
}

#divFooter
{
    height: 50px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
}
<div id="divHeader">
    Header
</div>
<div id="divContent">
    Content
</div>
<div id="divFooter">
    Footer
</div>
```

I've tried creating a parent div to house the existing 3 divs and giving that div a vertical-align:middle; but that gets me nowhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CSS2:

```
html,body {height:100%;}
body {display:table;}
div {display:table-row;}
#content {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

&

```
<body>
<div>header</div>
<div id="content">content</div>
<div>footer</div>
</body>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/doMwvJ

In old IE (<=7) you have to use trick with absolute positioning that marxidad mentioned.

And in latest browsers [you can use flexbox instead](http://flexboxin5.com/).

Comment: Please re-visit this.  It either doesn't work or is outdated.  If you add background color to the header and footer, it is obvious that this is not working as advertised.

Comment: add background:red; to only the Header div, and see that "content" is actually NOT centered, but simply directly under a large header.  Also, just straight up delete the vertical-align:middle, and see that it has no effect whatsoever because nothing is actually vertically aligned.  And for the real test, make the header an actual height like 20% of the window as you'd normally have, and see that "content" is directly under it, not vertically centered between "header" and "footer".

Comment: @Suamere I see. I've fixed the example by adding `display:table-cell` to `#content`

Answer (score 1):

In alternative, as far as I remember, you can using hacks like [this](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/priklady/vertical-align-final-solution-en.html) (more info [here](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html)).

Answer (score 0):

You need to either set the `height` of the div to fill the whole content area or its coordinates have to be in the center. Something like `top:50%; left:50%` but of course that will make the div a bit off to the bottom-right.

Comment: If you add margin-top:-25%; margin-left:-25%; that should re-centre the element.

Comment: % in margin refers to size of container, not the element. You need to use absolute size there.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try:

```
#divHeader
{
    height: 50px;
}

#divContent
{
    /*position:absolute;*/
    width: 900px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#divFooter
{
    height: 50px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Wondering for negative voting. At least share the reason first and then downvote.