# Set the height property of a DIV on a page that has a "footer"

Tags: css, html, height

Basically I want to have that middle blue body part scroll minus the scrollbar at the bottom. I know I can do this with javascript, i'm looking for more of a CSS solution.

On my actual site I have a div that is about 150px high that contains icons/images to do things and then the rest of the content needs to be scrollable vertically too, I want to find a solution for that too. I can cross that bridge next though.

So is there a way I can get that scrollbar to not "overflow" that bottom 30px? I know I can simulate it with another DIV there ( [How to create div to fill all space between header and footer div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206652/how-to-create-div-to-fill-all-space-between-header-and-footer-div) ) but i'm going to be dynamically adding/removing elements so that really isn't a usable solution for me.

Here is an example of a page I threw together trying to explain what I'm attempting here:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing Page</title>
<style  TYPE="text/css"> 
HTML
{
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
BODY
{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
DIV#content
{
    height:100%;
    margin-bottom:-30px;
    background-color:blue;
    overflow:auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="height:20px;background-color:green;width:100%;">top bar</div>
    <div id="content">
        main area
        <div style="height:2000px;width:500px;background-color:yellow;">cool kids<div>
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0;background-color:brown;height:30px;width:100%;">bottom bar</div>
</body>
</html>
```

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolute positioning.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing Page</title>
<style  TYPE="text/css"> 
HTML
{
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
BODY
{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
DIV#content
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 30px;
    background-color:blue;
    overflow:auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="height:20px;background-color:green;width:100%;">top bar</div>
    <div id="content">
        main area
        <div style="height:2000px;width:500px;background-color:yellow;">cool kids</div>
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0;background-color:brown;height:30px;width:100%;">bottom bar</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In DIV#content, use 'top: 20px' and it seems to work for me, too.

Answer (score 0):

Using a little JavaScript, I think we can solve your problem.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing Page</title>
<style  TYPE="text/css"> 

BODY
{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
DIV#header
{
    top: 0px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: green;
}
DIV#content
{
    top: 20px;
    bottom:30px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:blue;
    position: absolute;
    overflow:auto;
}
DIV#footer
{
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    position:absolute;
}
</style>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
function adjustContent()
{
    document.getElementById("content").style.height = window.height-50;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="adjustContent()" >
    <div id="header">top bar</div>
    <div id="content">
        main area
        <div style="height:2000px;width:500px;background-color:yellow;">cool kids</div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">bottom bar</div>
</body>
</html>
```

With the body onLoad event, the JavaScript resizes the content area to the correct height. The scrollbar does not overtake your footer, and your header and footer stay at the top and bottom of the page.

Also, adding content dynamically inside the content div should not break this layout.

Comment: Javascript is the only other solution I had in mind too, and it seems like I might need to go this route.