# How to push the footer below the content?

Tags: html, css

see 'http://ballpointradio.com/new/index.php', how do I get the footer (the Lorum Ipsum) to go below the lowest content, rather than moulding around it?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create div to fill all space between header and footer div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206652/how-to-create-div-to-fill-all-space-between-header-and-footer-div)

Answer (score 0):

Add `clear: both;` to your footer CSS