# How to fill the the available height on screen with the div for any height?

Tags: html, css

I want to fill the screen (width and height) on any size with a `<header>`:

```
<header></header>
    <div id="content"></div>
<footer></footer>
```

The `<header>` should always fill the whole screen on any height of monitor also in iPad, such that the content of `<div id="content">` will only be seen after scrolling, not before that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create div to fill all space between header and footer div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206652/how-to-create-div-to-fill-all-space-between-header-and-footer-div)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply give your `html`, `body` & `header` a height of 100%:

```
html, body, header {
    height: 100%
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tujsj/

Comment: @Jitendra Vyas: My solution does exactly that!

Comment: When I try in my layout <header> only take height upon the elements inside it. not 100%. What wrong I'm doing? I added `html, body, header {
    height: 100%
}` at the bottom of the css

Comment: @Jitendra Vyas: Is your `header` directly under the `body`? If not, then you'll also have to give that other element a `height: 100%`.

Comment: NO I have `Body` > `#container` > `header` > `#header-inner`

Comment: @Jitendra Vyas: Then, like I said, you'll have to do `html, body, #container, header { height: 100% }`.

Comment: @JosephSilber let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2735/discussion-between-jitendra-vyas-and-joseph-silber)

Comment: @Jitendra Vyas: Sorry, but that ship has sailed a long time ago. At least for me ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the new and so-useful-I-can't-imagine-what-took-W3C-so-long [vh](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/length) CSS unit:

```
<header style="height: 100vh"></header>
    <div id="content">must scroll to see this</div>
<footer></footer>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using javascript, specifically jquery to handle this?

If you include jquery in your head tag, then you can use something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#header").height($(window).height());
});
```

Comment: with the css approach, be sure to test on multiple browsers and versions as I have had mixed results with height 100%.