# How to keep a background image at background always at bottom in 100% height div?

Tags: javascript, css

This question is related to this [How to fill the the available height on screen with the div for any height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7148898/how-to-fill-the-the-available-height-on-screen-with-the-div-for-any-height)

How to keep a background image at background always at bottom in 100% height div? **and I want to show only a specific portion of background image?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/wJJTH/1/):

> [image: eg]

html:

```
<div id='a'>
    <div id='b'></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#a, html, body{
    height: 100%;
}
#a {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #dde;
    border: 1px solid #99c;
    position:relative;
    overflow: hidden
}

#b {
    width: 50px; 
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #99c;
    border: 1px solid #54a;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -25px;
    left: 125px;
}
```

You'll need to actually add the bg image to `b`.