# Middle div with 100% in CSS?

Tags: html, height, stretch, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS - percentage height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657964/css-percentage-height)

I can't get the middle div of 3 divs to fit 100% of available space.

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
    </div>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

My CSS is:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border:1px;
    vertical-align:top;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#333;
    height: 100%;
}
#container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#header {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #069;
}
#content {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #F60;
}
#footer {
    height: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #060;
}
```

Center div is in effect being 100%, but its not fitting available space.

**It is doing something like this:
If the screen is 500px**

```
30px
100% (500px)
30px
```

**What I need is:**

```
30px
100% (460px)
30px
```

Is this possible withouth using javascript?

Thanks a lot

**EDIT:

Sorry I meant Height I have 3 elements, header, middle and footer. Header and footer have fixed height, but I want middle to fit all available space**

Found another solution based on other stackoverflow question:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0 }
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align:top;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#333;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0;
}
#header
{
    height: 100px;
    background:#C60;
}

#container
{
    min-height: 100%; 
    height: auto !important; /*Cause footer to stick to bottom in IE 6*/
    height: 100%; 
    margin: 0 auto -100px; /*Allow for footer height*/
    vertical-align:bottom;
    background:#096;
}

#footer
{
    height: 100px; /*Push must be same height as Footer */
    background:#C60;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="header"> </div>
<div id="content"> </div>
</div>
<div id="footer"> </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I do not understand what you're asking. 100% means 100% of the width of the parent element -- so if you're in a 500px wide space, 100% is all 500px. Or do you mean you want it to grow vertically?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657964/css-percentage-height

Comment: Sorry I meant Height
I have 3 elements, header, middle and footer. Header and footer have fixed height, but I want middle to fit all available space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rv4XS/).

html

```
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">header
    </div>
    <div id="content">qweW
    </div>
</div>
</div>
    <div id="footer">footer
    </div>
</body>
```

css

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0 }
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border:1px;
    vertical-align:top;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#333;
    height: 100%;
    background: #F60;
}
#container {
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 75px;
}
#wrap {min-height: 100%;}
#header {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #069;
}
#content {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#footer {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -75px;
    clear:both;
    height: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    background: green;
}
```

I tweaked your HTML to add a "wrapper" around the "container" div, and move the "footer" out of both.

Comment: Thanks that worked like a charm, I will study it to see what's going on.

Comment: @Jorge essentially it's an adaptation of a "sticky" header. If your footer is 100px tall, you give it relative positioning and -100px margin, and then give the wrapper of the above content a padding-bottom of 100px.

Comment: This is a slick way of accomplishing this. Nice one!

Comment: I found another solution based on this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206652/how-to-create-div-to-fill-all-space-between-header-and-footer-div

Answer (score 1):

You could position the div absolutely:

```
<body>    
    <div id="header">
    </div>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    </div>
</body>
```

and

```
#header {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #069;
}
#content {
    position:absolute;
    top: 100px;
    bottom: 75px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    background: #F60;
}
#footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 75px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #060;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it didn't work, still the same behaviour.

Comment: Oops, wrong version. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think that a good idea would be to fiddle with ['display:flexbox'](http://benfrain.com/understanding-the-css3-flexbox-flexible-box-layout-module/) to achieve that kind of responsiveness. Here is a good article about it.

Comment: Oh this is seriously cool. +1. Pity it's only for CSS3 and not backwards  compatible without hacks.