# w3.css how to fill main row with background image even if no content

Tags: css, fluid-layout, w3.css

I have a w3.css `card` and in it a `header`, `main`, and `footer`. I want the `main` - which has a `background-image` - to behave like `w3-rest` in the columns of a row of the w3.css `fluid-grid`, filling in all the width. In other words, I want it to stretch and hold the whole area available between the header and footer VERTICALLY, filling in all the HEIGHT.

See for example my code here:http://jsfiddle.net/pashute/qnj1ptu2/

```
<section id="section--theme-results" class="w3-card-4">
  <header class="w3-theme"><h4>Theme results</h4></header>
  <main id="secphone" 
        class="w3-card-4" 
        style="background-size: cover; 
               background-image: url('images/cellphone.png');">
    it is only showing a few lines of text<br>
    but I want it to span the whole height <br>
    and show the background phone image inside<br>
    I should not have to fill this with content<br> 
    and I want the whole bg image to show. 
  </main>
  <footer>The end</footer>
</section>
```

I want the whole `main` section to show all the rows so that the background image is totally shown.

How do I do so with w3.css? Or is there a semantic tag in HTML5 for such behavior?

Or must I style it manually in the style with `display: flex; flex-direction: column;` (as in answer here [How to create div to fill all space between header and footer div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206652/how-to-create-div-to-fill-all-space-between-header-and-footer-div) which is not working in any case...) ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Without code we can't help you, Please create snippet so someone has quickly fixed your issue. Cheers.

Comment: I'm not exactly a newbee...  :-)  but your right. So edited. Question is for people who know w3school's w3.css well.

Comment: and btw, the flex is not working with the w3.css for some reason... See my latest fiddle: (set with: `background-repeat: no-repeat;` and with: `background-size: cover` remarked out)  http://jsfiddle.net/pashute/qnj1ptu2/

Comment: Bump.  Can anybody take a look?