# Ionic4 - Angular- GoogleMaps - How to modify the viewport of the background Google Map accordingly to the components shown?

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, viewport, ionic4

I'm developing an Ionic/Angular app which implements GoogleMaps.

I want my app to have the Google Map always on fullscreen on the background. I wish the components to render over it but I want Google Maps to always return to me the correct target/center coordinates.

This is a little image explaining my issue:
[image]

Already tried solutions:

1. If I set on Ionic my map in an ion-content with fullscreen (which means it expands behind the header and the footer), I would not have access to the correct center shown. Plus, the Google logo wouldn't be visible, which violates their policy.
2. Put the ion-header/content/footer inside the map div. That doesn't work. I can't explain why.

Is there simply a sort of viewport editing tool in Google Maps js API that I just haven't found?

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**

Since the fullscreen feature of ion-content does not seem to be functional so far (maybe this answer has to be corrected in the future), I decided to drop the ion tags.

To make a functional background Google Map, I took its div as the root. Inside I placed 3 divs to make the header, the content and the footer like explained in this post:

[How to create div to fill all space between header and footer div](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38627224/3948710)

Thought this was doing the trick but my Google Maps wasn't able to interact with the user anymore, because the content div was catching the touch events. So I followed this trick, and did the work for me:

[HTML “overlay” which allows clicks to fall through to elements behind it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26931709/3948710)

Finally, to change my map viewport size without changing the real map size, I used the padding feature included in the Maps API which only pads the camera and not the whole Maps view:

[Google Maps API JS - Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map)

(Personally, I used the GoogleMapOptions interface of ionic-native/google-maps, but still the same feature)

Hope this helps anyone.