# How to keep content inside Footer and Header in React Component?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I know this might be asked a lot but somehow I can't find the solution. My project in React and my top component is setup up like this:

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <Router>
    <Header />
    <Switch>
      <All the routes />
    </Switch>
    <Footer />
  </Router>
</Provider>
```

As you can see I want to use Header and Footer in all my pages. With my current setup, it works when my content height is bigger than view-height. I mean footer stays always on the bottom. The problem becomes on my smaller pages where the page content is smaller than view-height but my footer is still slightly below the view-height.

My current css code (didn't include unnecessary code): 
Header

```css
padding: "0.2em 4em"
```

Content-Wrapper

```css
minHeight: "100%",
```

Footer

```css
padding: "3em"
```

One of the pages on the link (that shows how footer is below the `vh`. Header stays at the top as a default block element and is fine ): [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWCXS.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should make use of flexbox in this case. Your code is in react but I will try to use html and css so you can understand the rules you have to apply. Look at this example:

```css
.app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  padding: 15px 5px;
  background-color: pink
}

.footer {
  padding: 15px 5px;
  background-color: pink;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="header">
    Your Header
  </div>

  <div class="app-content">
    Your will have routes here that will render your components as required
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    Your Footer
  </div>
  <div>
```

Trick here is to use `margin-top` on footer and it will produce the result you are looking for.

Let me know if you have any further question or confusion on this.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. But my app aligned in this way. No app element. Only outer element is 'root' and body.

```
  <div class="header">
    Your Header
  </div>

  <div class="app-content">
 
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    Your Footer
  </div>
  <div>
```

Comment: Your code works when i apply app style to Reacts root. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51147756/10463875 also worked for me

Comment: Glad that it helped you. Happy coding!